# How to create live CD/bootable ISO from LFS build

Tags: linux, iso-image, bootable-media, livecd

I have completed the installation and configuration of LFS 8.0 System. Now I want to turn it into a bootable ISO. For that I followed the hint http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/boot-cd_easy.txt, but it doesn't work for me, i.e. when booting the system from the ISO created, it gives a kernel panic as shown in the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Any help to generate a live CD of the LFS build?

Comment: The boot is failing because the file `/linuxrc` does not exist in the rootfilesystem.   Check the contents of your rootfs.   FWIW the build instructions use a ramdisk, which is deprecated in favor of tmpfs.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, can you please suggest me some links in order to modify the hint or use some other procedure as the hint is too old, in order to able to create bootable iso or get a direction from that.